# Certain org-mode buffers keep saving automatically

Tags: org-mode, auto-save

Certain `org-mode` buffers seem to write to file automatically when left idle even for a second. I've tried disabling a few minor modes but to no avail. It makes it all the more difficult to debug this since it only happens with a few org-mode buffers.

Version:

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1344.72)
```

Enabled Minor modes in the buffer:

```
Async-Bytecomp-Package Auto-Composition Auto-Fill
Auto-Revert Blink-Cursor Company Delete-Selection Diff-Auto-Refine Disable-Mouse
File-Name-Shadow Flx-Ido Font-Lock Global-Auto-Revert Global-Company
Global-Font-Lock Global-Git-Commit Global-Prettify-Symbols Helm Ido-Everywhere
Ido-Vertical Line-Number Mac-Mouse-Wheel Magit-Auto-Revert Org-Bullets
Org-Indent Override-Global Recentf Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Smartparens
Smartparens-Global Tooltip Transient-Mark Window-Numbering Yas Yas-Global
```

My configuration is located at https://github.com/kirang89/.emacs.d.

I'd be really awesome if someone could help me out on this one. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it may be worthwhile to check the timers to see if you can get the name of a function that looks suspicious.  `M-x describe-variable RET timer-idle-list RET` and `M-x describe-variable RET timer-list RET`.  Be sure to check both variables.

Comment: Ah, that was the clue I was looking for. I found a `deft-auto-save` function that runs instantly when idle. Delaying the interval did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the suggestion by @lawlist, I ran `M-x describe-variable RET timer-idle-list RET` to find out that a function named `deft-auto-save` ran instantly after Emacs went idle. Setting

`(setq deft-auto-save-interval 20)`

did the trick. Apparently, this interval matters only for org files that were launched by deft. This explains why the autosaving behaviour wasn't consistent across all org-mode buffers that I dealt with.

Comment: Yes, auto-saving is a feature of deft and isn't really related to org mode -- I think deft uses text mode by default.